# LUKS and Nuke key installtion on Ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, privacy

When you install Ubuntu there's an option to encrypt the installation. I didn't select that, can I still encrypt Ubuntu? I do not want to encrypt my home folder I would like to encrypt Ubuntu as if I did select that option on the setup process. Also I recently saw that Offensive Security added the NUKE key feature to Kali's encrypted partitioning and LVM option. Can I install that on Ubuntu as well?

Comment: The encryption Ubuntu offers on install is based on ecryptfs. That is file encryption and only encrypts the home folder. If you want a full block device encryption and a bootable Ubuntu you need to do it yourself manually. Search for `luks` (the encryption) & `lvm` (you need logical volumes because booting should be possible) & Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/95159/how-can-i-encrypt-ubuntu-filesystems-only

Comment: So I can't encrypt the Ubuntu system partition like the setup option?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add the NUKE feature to Ubuntu crypsetup!
You need der sourcecode from crypsetup, the patch for cryptsetup-1.6.6...

Then you can compile new libcryptsetup and cryptsetup with nuke feature.

This patch is for 1.6.6-5 (Ubuntu 16.04), for other version you neeed other patch, please visit the link!

get the patch (take a look http://deriv.debian.net/patches/c/cryptsetup/)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev libdevmapper-dev libpopt-dev uuid-dev libtool automake autopoint debhelper xsltproc docbook-xsl dpkg-dev
sudo apt-get source cryptsetup

wget http://deriv.debian.net/patches/c/cryptsetup/Debian_cryptsetup_2:1.6.6-5_Kali_cryptsetup_2:1.6.6-5kali1.debian.patch
```

extract source code from cryptsetup

```
cd cryptsetup-1.6.6
```

now its time to patch

```
patch -p1 < ../cryptsetup-nuke-keys/cryptsetup.patch
```

please corret the path, in my folder i have modified...

after patching, create DEB files for ubuntu

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

now its time to install

```
sudo dpkg -i ../libcryptsetup*.deb
sudo dpkg -i ../cryptsetup*.deb
```

edit:

I have made a simple shell script to patch and compile cryptsetup for Ubuntu 16.04. 
Please be careful!

run it with sudo!

```
#!/bin/sh

apt-get update
apt-get install libgcrypt11-dev libdevmapper-dev libpopt-dev uuid-dev libtool automake autopoint debhelper xsltproc docbook-xsl dpkg-dev

apt-get source cryptsetup
wget http://deriv.debian.net/patches/c/cryptsetup/Debian_cryptsetup_2:1.6.6-5_Kali_cryptsetup_2:1.6.6-5kali1.debian.patch

cd cryptsetup-1.6.6
patch -p1 < ../Debian_cryptsetup_2:1.6.6-5_Kali_cryptsetup_2:1.6.6-5kali1.debian.patch

dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

After that, you can install with

```
sudo dpkg -i ../libcryptsetup*.deb
sudo dpkg -i ../cryptsetup*.deb
```

check with

```
cryptsetup --help | grep luksAddNuke
```

should look like

*luksAddNuke  [] - add NUKE to LUKS device*

Now you can add nuke keys with

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddNuke /dev/sda5
```

With a standard Ubuntu installation it is normal sda5 !

Now make a backup of the header!

```
sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda5 --header-backup-file luks-backup
```

copy the file **luks-backup** on save location, if you wipe the header with nuke password, you can recover the header with linux live system!

make sure, that ubuntu update dont install the "normal" cryptsetup

```
sudo apt-mark hold cryptsetup-bin libcryptsetup4
```

check upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

looks like this

*Die folgenden Pakete sind zurückgehalten worden:
  **cryptsetup-bin libcryptsetup4** linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic ubuntu-core-launcher*

If i have some time, i would create ppa.

roema

Comment: If you like, i can send you a .deb file for installing.

Comment: If you want to make a package for this, please consider uploading it to a Launchpad PPA so that everyone in the community can profit from it. We don't really want to offer personal support here but create questions and answers useful for a wider audience.