# LUKS Nuke on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, luks, cryptsetup

So I've been searching through the Internet recently about a LUKS nuke patch from Offensoce Security for cryptsetup, but all of the places I've looked have the patch for cryptsetup 1.6.6 or earlier, while I have cryptsetup 2.0.2. I haven't been able to get any of the patches to work with my version, so does anyone know how to set it up so that I can add the luksAddNuke option to cryptsetup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this could happen, due to lack of resources:

1. The only available Kali-patch is:
    `Debian_cryptsetup_2:2.0.6-1_Kali_cryptsetup_2:2.0.6-1kali1.debian.patch` and
   can be found in [debian.net](http://deriv.debian.net/patches/c/cryptsetup/).
2. The latest and only `cryptsetup` version available for Ubuntu 18.04
       (Bionic) is 2.0.2 and can be found in [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup).
3. The latest Kali `cryptsetup` version that actually works can be
       found in Kali git repository [here](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/cryptsetup).

I tried combine all the above and do the same proccess as shown on this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821881/luks-and-nuke-key-installtion-on-ubuntu), but no luck.

Also, the [Kali Binary](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/c/cryptsetup/)(deb) of `cryptsetup_2.3.1` has unmet dependecies on Ubuntu 18.04 and is broken.

Currently, with the available resources I belive that is not possible to make it work even for an oldest version (1.6.6), unless if an expert put his hands-on and write down some code.

To conclude, if you really want to use this feature, my suggestion is to switch into Kali-Linux distribution.

Comment: Yeah, after lots of searching, I found that there's really no easy way to implement nuke in new versions of cryptsetup. The developer answers a request for it in [this thread](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/198) on the GitLab page that explains that you could create a wrapper using an erase commend. The developer stands against a "nuke" option because he doesn't see a legitimate use for it (see line 1806 in [the FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/FAQ) for his explanation. While I disagree with it, there isn't anything that will change their mind.